# Can CSS3 drop-down menu fade-in and fade-out?

Tags: css

I've implemented a drop-down menu with CSS3 that fades in the drop-down nicely when the parent `li` is hovered. But the drop-down will not fade-out and here's why. Since you can't transition the display property, the fade is accomplished by transitioning the opacity. Since just the opacity is transitioned, you need to move the sub `ul` out of the way - otherwise the invisible sub-menu will appear when hovered.

I've created a JS Fiddle that demonstrates this- without the `left:1000px;` rule on `ul#mainNav li ul`, it will fade-out just fine. But then you can hover the invisible menu. - http://jsfiddle.net/YZvdm/

So how would I go about making it fade-out without making it not accidentally hoverable? `height:0;` will also eliminate the fade-out, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The key to making this work is using `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none` and using a `transition-delay` on the visibility until after `opacity` goes to 0.

```
.nav li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -prefixes-transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  -prefixes-transition-duration: .4s, 0s;
  -prefixes-transition-delay: 0s, .4s;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -prefixes-transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YZvdm/29/

Comment: This is for sure a good solution, but the only issue is that at the moment the page loads, the user will see the dropdown menu fading out for 0.4 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out is was a far-better solution for me to simply implement a jQuery fade-in and out, like so:

```
$(function() {

    $('#topNav ul').find('ul').show().hide();
    $('#topNav > ul > li').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeIn(300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeOut('fast');
    });

}
```

Comment: to be honest, yes, this is what I would do. As trendy as it is to use CSS transitions, they're complex to write and have limited browser support, whereas the jQuery script is easy to write, easy to understand and works everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Github to an all-CSS dropdown with fade-in and fade-out. It should be able to do everything you can do with Javascript.

http://github.com/jmeas/CSS3-Dropdown-With-Fade

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo on Codepen and that is work on Firefox or others:

http://codepen.io/hayatbiralem/pen/Gdfie

Hope this helps.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's a nice menu. It should be noted that you're still using javascript, but it integrates CSS animations nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested this, but you should be able to get around it by defining your own special 'delayed' animation, and applying it to the sub-menus.

```
#mainNav > li > ul {  
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;  
    -moz-animation-name: delaySlide;     
}  

@-moz-keyframes delaySlide {  
    from {  
      height: auto;  
    }  

    95% {  
       height: auto;
    }  
    to {  
      height: 0;  
    }     
}
```

Doing so, and timing it properly, should make your menu's height animation happen *after* the fadeout.

Sample code taken off https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations#Defining_the_animation_sequence_using_keyframes

Comment: Are you using webkit or gecko?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to change it to -webkit- for chrome etc.

Comment: @Jerry - or better yet, use both (plus the un-prefixed version as well) to support both browsers at once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party, but here is what I ended up with faced with a similar prospect:

Fiddle:
https://jsbin.com/bibokaqumi/1/edit?html,css,output

Markup:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link One</li>
    <li class="sub">Link Two
      <ul>
        <li>Sub-Link One</li>
        <li>Sub-Link Two</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Link Three</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS3:

```
nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    height: 100px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    float: left;
}

    nav > ul > li.sub {
        position: relative;
    }

        nav > ul > li.sub ul {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        nav > ul > li.sub ul {
            opacity: 0;
            transition-property: opacity;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
        }

        nav > ul > li.sub:hover ul {
            opacity: 1;
            transition-delay: 0.1s;
            visibility: visible;
        }
```